# What is a recommended way to store and load enormous tabular dataset that doesn't fit to memory

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, dataset, pytorch-dataloader, dataloader

I am trying to figure out the optimal way to store and load a large TABULAR dataset (around 500GB in total) when it comes to training a PyTorch model. Specifically, my inquiries are the following:

1. What is the best way to store a huge tabular dataset (what format) for PyTorch training?
2. What is the best way to load and feed the dataset during model training (Dataset and Dataloader)

The requirements are:

1. Cannot load the entire dataset in memory (dataset is too big)
2. Batch size should be flexible

I have tried storing the dataset as chunked .npy files and .parquet files (each file contains multiple records) but I couldn't find a good solution to load and feed either format.

Comment: In your pytorch dataloader, you can loop through all the chunked files you created and load them one by one into memory as you are training the model.